# weird results with like operator on mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I'm using php to do the query. my query is the next:

```
$getDatos = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT hunlunngram.n_palabra, palabra FROM hunlunngram, tablanombre, tablaadjetivo, tablaverbo WHERE palabra LIKE '%s' OR raiz LIKE '%s' OR infinitivo LIKE '%s' OR participio LIKE '%s' OR gerundio LIKE '%s' OR presente1s LIKE '%s' OR presente2s LIKE '%s' OR presente3s LIKE '%s' OR presente1p LIKE '%s' OR presente2p LIKE '%s' OR presente3p LIKE '%s' OR presenteSubj1s LIKE '%s' OR presenteSubj2s LIKE '%s' OR presenteSubj3s LIKE '%s' OR presenteSubj1p LIKE '%s' OR presenteSubj2p LIKE '%s' OR presenteSubj3p LIKE '%s' OR pasado1s LIKE '%s' OR pasado2s LIKE '%s' OR pasado3s LIKE '%s' OR pasado1p LIKE '%s' OR pasado2p LIKE '%s' OR pasado3p LIKE '%s' OR pasadoSubj1s LIKE '%s' OR pasadoSubj2s LIKE '%s' OR pasadoSubj3s LIKE '%s' OR pasadoSubj1p LIKE '%s' OR pasadoSubj2p LIKE '%s' OR pasadoSubj3p LIKE '%s' OR futuro1s LIKE '%s' OR futuro2s LIKE '%s' OR futuro3s LIKE '%s' OR futuro1p LIKE '%s' OR futuro2p LIKE '%s' OR futuro3p LIKE '%s' OR futuroSubj1s LIKE '%s' OR futuroSubj2s LIKE '%s' OR futuroSubj3s LIKE '%s' OR futuroSubj1p LIKE '%s' OR futuroSubj2p LIKE '%s' OR futuroSubj3p LIKE '%s' OR futuroComp1s LIKE '%s' OR futuroComp2s LIKE '%s' OR futuroComp3s LIKE '%s' OR futuroComp1p LIKE '%s' OR futuroComp2p LIKE '%s' OR futuroComp3p LIKE '%s' OR condicional1s LIKE '%s' OR condicional2s LIKE '%s' OR condicional3s LIKE '%s' OR condicional1p LIKE '%s' OR condicional2p LIKE '%s' OR condicional3p LIKE '%s' OR condicionalComp1s LIKE '%s' OR condicionalComp2s LIKE '%s' OR condicionalComp3s LIKE '%s' OR condicionalComp1p LIKE '%s' OR condicionalComp2p LIKE '%s' OR condicionalComp3p LIKE '%s' OR plural LIKE '%s' OR singularDefinido LIKE '%s' OR pluralDefinido LIKE '%s' OR singularGenitivo LIKE '%s' OR pluralGenitivo LIKE '%s' OR singularDefinidoGenitivo LIKE '%s' OR pluralDefinidoGenitivo LIKE '%s' OR comparativo LIKE '%s' OR superlativo LIKE '%s' OR positivoAdverbio LIKE '%s' OR comparativoAdverbio LIKE '%s' OR superlativoAdverbio LIKE '%s'", $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"], $_GET["búsqueda"]);
```

the thing is:
when `$_GET["búsqueda"]` is for example 'an' or 'øn' or 'æg' all goes correctly and I receive the correct row.
but when `$_GET["búsqueda"]` is/begins with 'æn' I receive all rows.

That's just confusing ._.

Comment: Try to put [COLLATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) in your SQL statement

Comment: Ok, the problem was that I shouldn't have mixed all the tables like that. I managed to get it correctly.